# Passing nil to nonnull method argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

In recent versions of Objective-C, you can add nullability annotations to your pointers, to specify when things can and cannot be `nil`. That makes syntax like this legal:

```
-(void)doSomething:(nonnull NSString *)param;
```

This tells the compiler that `param` should never be `nil`. However, it's not an error to pass it `nil`. Thus, in my API, I'm testing to make sure my methods do sane things when `nil` is passed, just in case. However, I'm noticing that when passes `nil`, parameters marked to be `nonnull` are automatically converted to an empty instance of their type. For example, if I called the above example like this:

```
[self doSomething:nil];
```

`param` would be an empty string inside the method, and not `nil`, as I would expect. Is this documented, intended behavior? If so, is there a way to have it still be treated as `nil`, so I can more effectively handle it?

Comment: I just tested, and I don't see the behavior you describe.  You're doing something in your `doSomething:` method to give you that empty string.

Comment: Oddly enough, on my machine (Public Xcode 7.3, OS X 10.11.4, iOS sim iPhone 6s Plus iOS 9.3), this: `-(void)doSomething:(NSString *)param{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([param class]));` says it's an `__NSCFConstantString` (which is basically `NSString`)

Comment: I just modified my example to match, and I get the same result as before.  The string printed by the `NSLog()` statement is `(null)`, because I am passing `nil`.

Comment: As per my answer, it seemed to be an odd bug in my system, but I worked it out. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what was really going on (especially if it's not reproducible on another system), but the standard delete DerivedData and a clean build seemed to fix the issue, for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
[self doSomething:[NSNull null]];
```

if you have

```
-(void)doSomething:(nonnull id)param;
```

Otherwise you should call

```
[self doSomething:@""];
```

Comment: That isn't what the OP is asking. He wants to know if it's intended behaviour that the compiler converts `nil` to `@""`.